# How do I make an image work by command in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, command, prompt

This doesn't seem to be working

```
<script>
function imageCommand() {
    var imgdraw = prompt("type in an image adress")
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imgdraw;
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:imageCommand()">click here to draw something on the screen</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append created image object somewhere. For example to the `body`:

```
function imageCommand() {
    var imgdraw = prompt("type in an image adress")
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = imgdraw;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```